# Supporting 100+ WiFi Devices at a time

Tags: load-balancer

I have a co-working space where there are around 50 devices that needs to be connected to a WiFi.

**The setup that I have now**:

1. I am using 4 connections from different ISPs with varying bandwidth.
2. All of these connections are connected as WAN to my [TP-Link TL-R480T+ Load Balancer](http://www.amazon.in/TP-Link-TL-R480T-Balance-Broadband-Router/dp/B0019MGNUY/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1465930303&sr=1-1&keywords=TL-R480T%2B), which then gives me the aggregated bandwidth.
3. The output of the Load Balancer then goes to an unmanaged ethernet switch
4. Then from the switch, I am connecting 2 [UniFi AP LR](http://www.amazon.in/Ubiquiti-UniFi-Enterprise-System-Range/dp/B00HXT8S9G/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1465930436&sr=8-1&keywords=unifi) access points to distribute the internet connection.

This works fine till 30-35 devices, but becomes very slow beyond that.

According to me, the Load Balancer is the bottleneck. I am not sure though.

I want to support more than 50 devices. How can I do that?

Note: I need the load balancer to combine all my internet connections. If you are suggesting to replace that, please give an alternative that can combine 4 or more WAN connections.

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but the 30-35 device figure sounds close to the max number of active devices that can be supported by an AP. Are you sure your devices are reasonably split between your two APs ? What makes you think the LB is the culprit ?

Comment: Yes, they automatically get split by UniFi Controller. I have set the max devices on each AP to be 25. So it automatically distributes them evenly.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the load balancer or several other things:

Most APs slow down with more than 20 clients.

1. It could be channel contention.  Make sure you have disabled low
   speeds (1-11Mbps) on each AP.
2. It could be co-channel interference.  Make sure the APs are on
   different channels.
3. It could be that clients are not distributed evenly between APs. 
   Hard to fix that one without a wireless controller.

Comment: 1. I don't know how to disable low speeds using UniFi controller.
2. The APs are on different channels.
3. This is not the case. The controller does that for me.